# catch double click on textview android

Tags: java, android

i want to catch double click on textview for that i have used below code

but it still not working :(

```
TextView txtOne;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOne);
    txtOne.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("DRAG");
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        }
    });
}

final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Double Tap");
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("One Click");
                return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
            }


        });
```

only drag is calling but not "Double Tap" and "One Click" never called

Comment: Is your problem get solved?

Comment: no @ChintanRathod it not solving :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following steps.

#### Step 1

Write following code in your activity.

```
// initialize the Gesture Detector
gd = new GestureDetector(this,new OnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});

// set the on Double tap listener
gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"Double Tap",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // if the second tap hadn't been released and it's being moved

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

});
```

#### Step 2

Write following code for activity. Here `gd` will be `GestureDetector` object.

```
txt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gd.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: it's only detecting "onShowPress and onLongPress"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

[GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)

Try:

[GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html)

Comment: can u describe me where should i have to use?

Comment: @EleshBaraiya one more thing, I doubt your XML layout code you have taken for TextView, can you post XML layout?

Answer (score 1):

For `SimpleGestureDetector`, you need to override `onDown()` and return `true` to trigger double tap detector.

> Whether or not you use `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`, it's best practice to implement an `onDown()` method that returns `true`. This is because all gestures begin with an `onDown()` message. If you return `false` from `onDown()`, as `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` does by default, the system assumes that you want to ignore the rest of the gesture, and the other methods of `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` never get called. This has the potential to cause unexpected problems in your app. The only time you should return `false` from `onDown()` is if you truly want to ignore an entire gesture.

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a good site for performing double click... I used it and worked
[doubleCLICK](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/)