# Selector on textView requierd two click to do action

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-selector

I have selector line on my textView.

selector.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--<item android:drawable="@drawable/select_white" android:state_activated="true"/>-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_white" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_white" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select_none"/>
</selector>
```

and i set as background for my textView :

```
                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/displayPlace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/place"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_main"/>
```

when i click on text view selector appeared fine, but i have to do action on my click, so to do my action it's rquired to click twice, I have tried to remove `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` line but it make selector visible for a bit of second and gone.

How i can do action on first click with selector ?

My on Click :

```
place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragment = new PlaceFragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment);
            Fragment fragment2 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
            if (fragment2 != null)
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment2).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: show me you java code

Comment: @sushantgosavi it's just a click metho, btw i updated it.

Comment: but i have to do action on my click  what was that do u mean u click on other view>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use `setOnFocusChangeListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way you can use double click

1) Using timer in OnClickListener  https://gist.github.com/srix55/ec64d2f6a371c80bbbc4
2) Using GestureDetector  **onDoubleTap**  listnerer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531025/4741746   and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21449185/4741746